# Tor Browser does not set cookie expiry time

Tags: php, session, cookies, time, tor

I use set_cookie function and set TTL to 10 seconds.

Example response from server:

```
Set-Cookie: COOKIE_10=VALUE; expires=Sun, 07-Nov-2021 16:40:43 GMT; Max-Age=10; path=/
```

After that I checked cookie expiry time in TOR browser:

```
"Expires": "At the end of the session",
    "Expires raw": "0",
```

It's always "At the end of the session"
I checked in Chrome and cookie expiry time working fine.
Is any way to make TOR set expiry date correctly?

Answer (score 0):

### Tor default settings

If you open `about:config`, and search for `Network.cookie.lifetimePolicy`, you can see the value is set to 2.

[image]

Change it to 0 to let it be supplied by the server. You can read more about it here: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.cookie.lifetimePolicy